# Access the value assigned to the clicked submit button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I noticed one pecular thing. When there are several submit buttons in your HTML form like so:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit_button", value="b1"></button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_button", value="b2"></button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_button", value="b2"></button>
```

..and you do this:

```
var $form = $('#my_html_form');
$form.submit(function() {
        if (!checkPassed && !hasRequiredValue) {
            bootbox.confirm('Are you sure that you don\'t need <strong>{requiredValue}</strong> parameter?', function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    checkPassed = true;
                    $form.submit();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }        
});
```

the field `submit_button` does not get submitted at all, it's just not present in the request data.

Would there be a way to force JS to submit data together with the value of the submit button clicked?

I will only add that if the form is submited with PHP and not JS, the `submit_button` field is present and has the value of `b1`, `b2`, or `b3` - depending on which button was clicked.

P.S. I just thought that the source of the problem might be that I'm using `<button>` instead of `<input>`. However, as I said, it's all good with PHP.

Comment: So you want to get the value before the next page loads? or on the next page?

Comment: I'd say a [radio input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radio) would be more suited for this.

Answer (score 1):

Only a successful submit button will be included in the form data.

A successful submit button is one that is used to submit the form.

Your JavaScript runs on the submit event and:

- Always cancels the submission of the form
- Sometimes submits the form with JS

Since you are submitting the form with JS instead of the submit button, none of the submit buttons are successful.

Change your JS so that it:

- Sometimes cancels the submission of the form

Such:

```
$form.submit(function() {
    // Add a NOT condition here
    if (!<someCondition>) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

---

Regarding the update:

OK, so you are always canceling the submission, and using a DOM based widget to ask for confirmation.

In that case, you need to capture the value of the submit button separately.

The information isn't exposed to the submit event so you need to do it on the click event of the submit button.

Add a hidden input to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit_button">
```

Then add another event handler:

```
$form.on("click", '[name="submit_button"]', function (event) {
    $form.find('[type="hidden"][name="submit_button"]').val(
        $(this).val()
    );
});
```

Comment: The example JS I gave is overly simplified (sorry this might have been misleading), in reality it just submits the form when the user clicks "OK" on the conifrmation box. Otherwise it returns false. However, even if the user confirms, the form is submitted, but withoug the value of teh submit button.

Comment: @luqo33 — The confirmation box? So `<someCondition>` is `confirm("something");`? Then just do that I said.

Comment: I've now updated my question with the actual fragment of code

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the value of the button

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
    var button = $(this).data('clicked', $(event.target));
    var value = button.val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful snippet. However, the point is to 'force' `submit()` to submit the value of the submit button together with other form fields. Perhaps it could be done without explicitly intercepting the submit button value.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
$("button[name=submit_button]").click(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tw698hvs/